# How to use PDFNet pdfviwer with annotations in Xamarin Cross platform (xamarin forms in PCL)

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, pdfnet

I want to implement PDF Viewer with annotations in Xamarin Cross Platform apps (UWP, Android & ios). As per suggestion on (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/pdfnet-mobile-sdk?version=1.0.0). How can we implement PDFnet PDFViewer in Xamarin Forms portable library? since they written separate libraries and code for different platforms or should we use native apps?.

Answer (score 0):

That is an old version that is no longer updated. To get the latest Xamarin SDK please fill in this form.
https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/request_trial.html